# Graphics Context is Twice as Big as Expected

Tags: swift, macos, core-graphics, graphicscontext

I am developing a Swift MacOS app for drawing. The following subset of my code shows my problem.

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        var window: NSWindow!
        window = NSWindow(contentRect: NSMakeRect( 0, 0, 1000, 1000 ),styleMask:[.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable], backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)

        print("windowHeight = \(window.frame.height)")
        print("windowWidth  = \(window.frame.width)")
    
        let view = Renderer( frame:NSMakeRect( 0, 0, 1000, 1000 ) )
        view.autoresizingMask = [.width, .height]
        window.contentView!.addSubview (view)

        print("viewHeight = \(view.frame.height)")
        print("viewWidth  = \(view.frame.width)")
    }
        
    func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool{return true}
    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) { }
}

let appDelegate = AppDelegate()
let application = NSApplication.shared
application.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
application.delegate = appDelegate
application.activate(ignoringOtherApps:true)
application.run()


class Renderer: NSView {
            
    override func draw(_ rect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        
        print("rectHeight = \(rect.height)")
        print("rectWidth  = \(rect.width)")
        
        guard let gc = NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext else {return}  // gc = graphics context
        
        print("gc.height = \(gc.height)")
        print("gc.width  = \(gc.width)")
        
        // The rest of my drawing code goes here.
    }
}
```

When running this code, the printout is:

```
    windowHeight = 1022.0   windowWidth = 1000.0
    viewHeight   = 1000.0   viewWidth   = 1000.0
    rectHeight   = 1000.0   rectWidth   = 1000.0
    gc.height    = 2000     gc.width    = 2000
```

When I've declared the window, view, and rect to all be of size 1000 by 1000, why does the current GraphicsContext say that it is size 2000 by 2000 ?

Comment: That's because the unit is the number of pixels, not the number of points?

Comment: Thank you.  You solved my problem.  I did not realize that using a GraphicsContext moved my drawing out of the logical coordinate system and into a device coordinate space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your computer has a double resolution (Retina) screen.

Comment: Thank you.  I did not realize that using a GraphicsContext moves my drawing code from point-based to pixel-based.

Comment: Well, it has to draw on the screen you've got, so it has a scale (handled by the `ctm`). You used the `height` and `width` values, which, as docs tell you, is _pixel_ based. But when you actually draw into the graphics context, you draw in _points._ So, as you very well express it, your drawing is point-based but the output of the graphics context (represented by its actual bits) is pixel-based. See my http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html#_points_and_pixels. The question you likely want answered is better answered by getting the default `boundingBoxOfClipPath`.